# Cannot read property 'x' of undefined - snake [ solved ]

Tags: javascript

-- Edit -

The problem was in the draw function
I was calling player.update();
but i should have called player.update(apple);
 Thanks for the Help

Im coding snake from scratch, and I think the problem is with the snake parts. But I don't see it.
I've tried rewriting my code three times
It's the first time I've tried anything like this so Im no help to what the problem may be.
- Heres the link to the program if you want to use this instead of the code here, just to see whats goin on
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/snakeprototype/4797370687356928
Any help is appreciated ~thanks

```
var gameSpeed = 10;

// Declare Functions
var Player;
var Part;
var UpdateParts;
var Apple;

/*
KeyCode functions

*/

var parts = [];

var Part = function(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.pX = this.x;
    this.pY = this.y;
};

var Player = function()
{
    parts[0] = new Part(200, 200);
    parts[1] = new Part(200, 210);
    parts[2] = new Part(200, 220);

    this.update = function(apple)
    {
        if (parts[0].x === apple.x && parts[0].y === apple.y)
        {
            apple.newApple();
        }
        // Square
        fill(27, 168, 36);
        rect(parts[0].x, parts[0].y, 10, 10);
        /*
        Change Directions
        */

        if (frameCount % gameSpeed === 0)
        {
            //move
            if (this.direction === "up") 
            {
                parts[0].y-=this.speed;
            }
            if (this.direction === "down") 
            {
                parts[0].y+=this.speed;
            }
            if (this.direction === "left") 
            {
                parts[0].x-=this.speed;
            }        
            if (this.direction === "right") 
            {
                parts[0].x+=this.speed;
            }
        }
    };
};

var UpdateParts = function()
{
    for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i++)
    {
        if (frameCount % gameSpeed === 0)
        {
             parts[i].pX = parts[i].x;
             parts[i].pY = parts[i].y;
             parts[i].x = parts[i-1].pX;
             parts[i].y = parts[i-1].pY;
        }
    }
};

/*
Apple function

*/

var apple = new Apple();
var player = new Player();
```

Comment: The error means that you are calling property x on an object that does not exist (even though you probably think it exists). When I debug I like to add console logs or debuggers to check what my object values are and figure out why they are undefined

Comment: Thanks Ill try that

Comment: What is `apple` ? Could you try to `console.log(apple)` ?

Comment: Apple seems to be undefined.